# Can't write text file

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Dim tb As TextBox
Dim matches() As Control
Dim rtb2 As New RichTextBox
For i As Integer = 1 To 60
    matches = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
        tb = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
        rtb2.AppendText(vbNewLine & "--" & vbNewLine & tb.Text)
    End If
    rtb2.savefile("thoikhoabieu.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
Next
```

I use this code to write text to file in vb and the file is located in the program folder but when I use this code, the **thoikhoabieu.txt** file doesn't have anything. Is that a problem? I have tried alternative ways of writing text in vb but failed.

Comment: Your file will have the content of the last textbox found. Move the SaveFile call outside the for loop

Comment: Why  would you use this complicated richtextbox-workaround instead of simply using `File.WriteAllText` (or `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText`, if you are a fan of the VB-specific My namespace)?

Comment: @Steve Even if I agree that `saveFile` should be called outside the loop I think that the file should contains the content of all the `TextBox`es because he appends the `TextBox` content to the `RichTextBox`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: How you check that file is empty? Are you sure you check correct file in correct directory?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint inside the `if`, is it reached?

Comment: Open the text file and it's empty, completely empty

Answer (score 0):

you are just saving the file but not writing in it. 
Try to use Stream Writer instead.
If you are not sure about the Path use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory method and print out your path in MsgBox

Comment: [RichTextBox.SaveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e4a710b1(v=vs.110).aspx) should save the content of the RichTextBox to the specified file

Comment: I used the above code for another program and it works, idk why this is not work